# Is it possible to create a custom shaped button without svg?

Tags: html, button, svg

As I've realised by searching on the web for a way to create a custom shaped button, svg seems like the only way. But it has lots of compatibility issues. 
Is there any other way to create something with a custom shape?
And ofcourse I mean something that you will be able to click only inside the shape boundaries.

For example, I need a button shaped like a police badge.
And by compatibility issues I mean for example that Firefox doesn't support svg in external css. At least that's what I know. And I hope I can avoid clip-path

Comment: It depends on what you mean by custom shapes. What kind of a shape do you need? ... Regarding compatibility issues, what issues do you mean?

Comment: Downvoted - please add relevant information.  Specifically: what shape are you trying to make a button out of?

Comment: Here is an impressive list of how one can do: https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Comment: If compatibility with really old browsers is the concern you can use a regular image and the [area](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/area) element to make a clickable (non-rectangular) shape.

Comment: the area element is not what I'm looking for because it affects only the clickable area and the shape also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "Firefox doesn't support svg in external css" and how that effects what you want to do.  You may need to explain your requirements better.

Here's an example of a custom button.  It should work fine in all moderately recent browsers.

```html
<svg width="200" height="200">
  <a xlink:href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
    <polygon points="100,0 200,50 170,170 100,200 30,170 0,50"/>
  </a>
</svg>
```

**Update**

New example with clip-path and path for disbelieving OP:

```html
<svg width="200" height="200">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="cp">
      <path d="M100,0 L200,50 170,170 100,200 30,170 0,50 Z"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  
  <a xlink:href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
    <image width="200" height="200" xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/" clip-path="url(#cp)"/>
  </a>
</svg>
```

Comment: This does work though can I use this as a clip-path or can I just attach an overlay class to it with an image? And I've also tried this with path istead of polygon (for curved shape) and it never works.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by an "overlay class", but yes, you can use a clip-path.  It shouldn't matter whether you use a `<polygon>` or a `<path>`.

Comment: I've added an example that uses a path and a clipPath.

Comment: I mean add a second class to the button that has a background image. And as many times as I've tried using '<path> ' it doesn't work. At least with firefox

Comment: This path does work for me. Did you use a generator? or a shape converter? And another thing: is this only possible with the <a> tag? because I tried it with the <button> tag and it didnt work

Comment: I didn't use a generator, I wrote it by hand.  You cannot put a `<button>` in the SVG because that is not a valid SVG element.  If you put the SVG on a button it is just a image on a rectangular button.  You could potentially apply a clipPath or mask to the button, but clipping and masking of HTML elements is a little unreliable on browsers currently.

Comment: Ok. But can I use anything else in the svg tag or hust the <a> tag?

Comment: `<a>` is the only linking element that you can use in SVGs.  But you do have the option of attaching a click event to the `<path>` or `<polygon>` instead of using an `<a>` element.